# Create roles Identity framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with creating a role for users. I follow the guide below. https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17333/Custom-user-roles-and-rolebased-authorization-in-ASPNET-core/32835#.XOBFAcgzbcs

I added the "CreateRoles" method to "Startup.cs"

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        //adding custom roles
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Manager", "Member" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            //creating the roles and seeding them to the database
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }
        //creating a super user who could maintain the web app
        var poweruser = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],
            Email = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]
        };
        string UserPassword = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserPassword"];
        var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]);
        if (_user == null)
        {
            var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, UserPassword);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                //here we tie the new user to the "Admin" role 
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");
                }
        }
}
```

I call it in "Configure":

```
CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
```

When running the application, an exception occurs

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered.)

How to fix this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 . in general Did your error show u didn't register the costume  in>  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

Answer (score 0):

Append [AddRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilder.addroles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IdentityBuilder_AddRoles__1) to add Role services:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Or replace `AddDefaultIdentity` method with the `AddIdentity` method in the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```